# Using Serial as boolean function argument

Tags: serial

The following program compiles in the Arduino IDE.

```
void doSomething(bool) {}

void setup() {      
  doSomething(Serial);
}

void loop() {}
```

But, as expected, this one doesn't:

```
class MyClass {};

void doSomething(bool) {}

void setup() {   
  MyClass myClass;
  doSomething(myClass);
}

void loop() {}
```

The compiler returns the error `cannot convert 'MyClass' to 'bool' for argument '1' to 'void doSomething(bool)'`

---

Why is it possible to compile the former? Isn't Serial a normal class instance (of `HardwareSerial`)? Does it makes any sense to interpret `Serial` as a bool?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`HardwareSerial` [defines](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators) `operator bool()`, which allows it to be used in a boolean context.

Comment: And what is the purpose of the bool() operator?

Comment: Classes define whether and how their instances can be converted to bool, and what the resulting bool means. In the specific case of `HardwareSerial`, it means the serial port is ready: "This will only return false if querying the Leonardo's USB CDC serial connection before it is ready." — https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/IfSerial